# Firewall with ability to block manually temorarily ip addresses, ports?

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I have made a DDoS detection system that gives me info about malicious IP addresses and ports need to be blocked. Does anyone knows good solution of firewall, allowing me to do that. More automated than iptables. For ex.:
I write abstract example of the script for firewall:

IP=x.x.x.x

port=ALL

time = 60

and it will block all writen ip for 60 seconds.

Suggest any suitable firewall solutions, please

Comment: You may want to have a cron job that executes a shell script at certain times. The shell script would contain the specific iptables shell commands, which you need to be timed.